# Device Activity Report App Icons Not Getting Bigger

Tags: ios, swiftui, label

I am working on implementing [new Screen Time API (from WWDC 22)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/) in my app and I am trying to show app icons in the report by using `Label(:ApplicationToken)` initialiser and it works fine. However, all the app icons are very small unlike in the video from WWDC. If you take a look on the screenshot, I have app icons like on the right-most phone, but want smith like on the left-most.

[image]

Here is the code I have in my View in the `Device Activity Report Extension`:

```
@ViewBuilder
private func appIcon(for applicationToken: ApplicationToken?) -> some View
{
    if let applicationToken
    {
        Label(applicationToken)
            .labelStyle(BigAppIconLabelStyle())
    }
}

struct BigAppIconLabelStyle: LabelStyle
{
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.icon
            .scaleEffect(2) // Scale Effect increases the icon but destroys the quality
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50) // Frame The frame changes, but the icon is still tiny.
    }
}
```

I tried to adjust the `frame` and `font`, but the only thing that works is `scaleEffect`, but, as you can imagine, the quality of the icon is terrible in this case.
Apple's documentation is also not helping, so I was wondering how can I make this app icons bigger?